# Change BASE HREF for absolute references?

Tags: html, url

I copy a large html source of an external page (say, http://www.example.com/bar/something.html) into a directory in my PC (say, /xxx). The file 'something.html' contains many absolute references in the form `href="/bar/another.html"` or `src="/bar2/yetanother.jpg"` etc.

If I simply click 'something.html' (accessing it from my browser as 'file://') -- or even if I upload it to my own server and access it via 'http://' -- all those references will be looked in the same host where the file is. I still want them to be looked in the **original** host (i.e., http://www.example.com).

Had they been relative references (without the 1st slash), I would simple put `<base href=" http://www.example.com/">` in the HEAD section. **How can I achieve a similar effect with those absolute references??**

Consider also the case where something.html includes many other files (css, js, ...) which may also have such absolute references...

Comment: Please do not use domain names that are real or could be real when you present a dummy example. The name www.foo.com is real. Use e.g. www.example.com instead. (See [BCP 32](http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp32).) Also consider whether posting a real example is better.

Answer (score -3):

You have the terminology backwards: the reference `/bar/another.html` is a relative reference, not an absolute reference.  The `/` indicates to restart at the root of the resource. For `file:///` URLs, this will start at the root of the filesystem, but it's still relative.

If you add the `<base href="...">` it will prepend the `...` to the URL, unless the URL is indeed absolute (begins with `http://`, `ftp://`, `file://` etc)

If you use the base href as `file:///where_i_downloaded/`, you'll get resources linked from there (not from the root of the file system), or as `http://www.foo.com/` which would force the browser to attempt to load from the original server (attempt, because URLs for AJAX services may not work with this).

Comment: An URL starting with `/` is in fact an absolute URL with implicit domain name - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs
Therefore it is unaffected by `<base ...>`