# Change all links in a specific web app from root (absolute) to add a subfolder?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am deploying an app that is designed to run on the root and the html pages have a lot of links in the form:

```
/something/file.ext
```

like

```
/img/logo.png
/css/main.css
/js/app.js
```

and links too:

```
/link/to/url
```

I need to change them all into:

```
/subfolder/link/to/url
```

Is there any elegant way to do this without going page by page and changing it by hand?

I used Apache RewriteBase and HTML's base element..

I also read this question and answer which suggests what I'm doing should work:

[Change BASE HREF for absolute references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704672/change-base-href-for-absolute-references)

But it does not work!

I am doing this:

```
<base href="http://somesitename.com/subfoldername">
```

What happens is that the links still go to `http://somesitename.com/url` instead of the desired result.

Comment: Check that it is being properly setup by typing `document.baseURI` into your browser dev tools

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I was able to come up with is the following:

Mass search and replace of

```
<head>
```

With:

```
<head><base href="http://newsite.com/newfolder">
```

and then search and replace

```
"/ or '/
```

with

```
"
```

Your milage may vary. I also had to replace some urls inside the javascript code.
Anything that started with a forward slash.